# Passing a currying function from Rails to JavaScript

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I need to pass an URL to a .js file. This URL is generated by Rails and **accepts one argument**.

```
#routes
get "my_super/:some_id" => "controller1#my_super",

#index.html.haml
:javascript
  var myUrlFunc = "#{my_super_url}"; //my_super_url(...) expects one argument
```

And a .js file:

```
  $.ajax({
    url: myUrlFunc($("#active_user_id"));
  })
  //................
```

The point is I don't know `some_id` initially as it's dynamically chosen, it's chosen from a drop down list. So I have to a **function** `myUrlFunc` which takes one argument and returns the URL instead of the URL itself. I thought this would work that it didn't due to an error:

```
No route matches {:action=>"my_super", :controller=>"controller1"} missing required keys: [:some_id]
```

What do I do about this?

Comment: This may help you.. http://railscasts.com/episodes/324-passing-data-to-javascript?view=asciicast

Comment: @Gagan, but it doesn't explain how to pass a curried function from Rails to JS.

Comment: I am not that much expert as I am very new bee but trying to help you by giving some resource which can help you out. Check this http://spin.atomicobject.com/2013/11/22/pass-rails-data-angularjs/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you have found out, the routing helper won't let you call it with missing parameters. Further more ruby doesn't know how to serialize a ruby method into a javascript function.

One simple, if not particularly elegant would be to pass a dummy value to `my_super_url`. Your function would then be along the lines of

```
var myUrlFunc = function(id){
  var base = #{my_super_url("--DUMMY--")};
  return base.replace("--DUMMY--", id);
}
```